# Display a list and add new item in on list asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to create a view that will display a list in a table above and below a form to input new items to the same list, but I get this error:

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[NAOC_ROW.Models.tbContPaymentHist]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'NAOC_ROW.Models.tbContPaymentHist'.

Here is the view

```
    @model IEnumerable<NAOC_ROW.Models.tbContPaymentHist>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Payment List";
   
<section class="content">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <h3> Payment History</h3>
        <hr />

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="card card-primary card-outline">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h3 class="card-title">
                            <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                            Last Completed Payments
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body pad table-responsive">

                        @if (Model.Count() > 0)
                        {

                            @*scrolling bootstarp table, check css in top of this page*@
                            <div class="table-wrapper-scroll-y my-custom-scrollbar">

                                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped mb-0">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th scope="col">
                                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Datepaid)
                                            </th>
                                            <th scope="col">
                                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Amtpaid)
                                            </th>
                                            <th scope="col">
                                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Balance)
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>

                                       
                            </div>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <h5>No payments completed yet</h5>
                        }

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="card card-cyan card-outline">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h3 class="card-title">
                            <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                            Add New Payment
                        </h3>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card-body pad table-responsive">
                        
                        <p><strong>Monthly payments:</strong> &#x20A6;@String.Format("{0:#,##0.00}", @ViewBag.expected)</p>
                        <p><strong>Current balance:</strong> &#x20A6;@String.Format("{0:#,##0.00}", @ViewBag.bal)</p>
                        
                        @*<input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.ContractId" />*@
                        <hr />


                           
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="modal-info">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content bg-info">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Info Modal</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                    <input type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.bal" name="AmtExpected" />
                    <partial name="_AddNewPayment" />
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal -->

</section>

@section Scripts{
    @{
        <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
    }
}
```

I created a partial view as you can see in the script hoping to loose the error, but still did not work. I took out some parts of the code to reduce your time having to read the code. I left the necessary code.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: You have to post the action to show code you use to create a viewmodel

Comment: can you provide your action , model and pritial view code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error message, you pass the value of type `List<Model>` to Paritl view and use `@model.xxx.Model` in the partial view . so you can change some code like this:

**The first way** : you can use `@model IEnumerable<NAOC_ROW.Models.tbContPaymentHist>` in partial view;

**The second way** : you need to pass a model to the partial view
`<partial name="_AddNewPayment" model="new tbContPaymentHist()"/>`

Comment: Thank you. Worked perfectly.    
I used the second method:     
  
`The second way : you need to pass a model to the partial view <partial name="_AddNewPayment" model="new tbContPaymentHist()"/>`